# How to get width value set in css using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, width

After several attempts using `width()`, `outerWidth()` and `css("width)` I discovered that all of these methods return a calculated value (in my case always different from the original value), so how can I read the value I set for element `width` in my css?

Comment: it should always be same, unless there is some `padding` set. so get the value of padding aswell

Comment: infact, css("width") should work

Comment: @Rhea Unfortunately the value is not the same of css: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/14022

Comment: Sounds like you have an element inside you original element that may be expanding the width beyond what you have set in your stylesheet and all those answers, don't they read the question?

Comment: Provide a jsfiddle to test it or at least relevant html code

Comment: Can you provide some html and code you are trying ?

Answer (score 1):

Try  [OuterWidth](http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/)

```
$('#target').outerWidth(true);
```

> the padding and border are included in the calculation; if you pass true, the margin is also included.

Comment: This is not working for me. It returns a greater value also specifying  `includeMargin=true`. So I'd like to read the value directly from my CSS...